# nuxt js application builds local and starts on production with docker

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

I have a project developed on nuxt js. Now I want to employ it with docker. But for some reason, I need build it on my local machine of mac os. It would be better to run `npm install` on local machine. And then employing it on linux server of production environment. Can this task be done?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sure can be. Build your project normally (via `npm install`), then, inside your project directory, write a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM node:7.8.0-alpine

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add git

# Copy your already built project files inside image
COPY . .

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000

# start command
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Make sure your Dockerfile is in the project's root directory where you'd normally run `npm start`.

Then, in order to create a image with your project, just do:

```
$ docker build -t myapp .
```

and run it with:

```
$ docker run -it -p 3000:3000 myapp
```